# Conditional Inner join in sqlite python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have three tables  `a`, `b` and `c`.
Table `a` is related with table `b` through column `key`.
table `b` is related with table `c` through columns `word`, `sense` and `speech`. In addition table `c` holds column `id`.

Now some rows in a.word have no matching value with b.word, based on that
I want to `inner join` tables on condition if a.word = b.word then join, otherwise compare only a.end_key = b.key.

As a result I want to have table in form of `a` with extra columns of `start_id` and `end_id` from `c` matching with `key_start` and `key_end`.

I tried following sql command with python:

```
CREATE TABLE relations 
              AS
              SELECT * FROM 
                  c
              INNER JOIN 
                  a
              INNER JOIN
                  b
              ON 
                  a.end_key =  b.key
              AND
                  a.start_key = b.key
              AND
                  b.word = c.word
              AND
                  b.speech = c.speech
              AND
                  b.sense = c.sense
              OR
                  a.word  = b.word
```

a:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----------+
| key_start | key_end | word | relation  |
+-----------+---------+------+-----------+
| k5        | k1      | tree | h         |
| k7        | k2      | car  | m         |
| k200      | k3      | bad  | ho        |
+-----------+---------+------+-----------+
```

b:

```
+-----+------+--------+-------+
| key | word | speech | sense |
+-----+------+--------+-------+
| k5  | sky  | a      |     1 |
| k2  | car  | a      |     1 |
| k3  | bad  | n      |     2 |
+-----+------+--------+-------+
```

c:

```
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| id |  word   | speech | sense |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
|  0 | light   | a      |     1 |
|  0 | dark    | b      |     3 |
|  1 | neutral | a      |     2 |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
```

Edit for clarification:

The values of tables `a`, `b` and `c` hold hundreds thousands lines, so there are matching values in the tables. Table `a` is related to table `b` with `end_key` ~ `key` and `start_key`~`key` relation. Table `b` is related to `c` through `word` `sense` and `speech`, there are values which match in each of these columns.

The desired table is in form

`start_id`|`key_start`|`key_end`|`end_id`|`relation`

Where `start_id` matches `key_start` and `key_end` matches `end_id`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT new answer**
The problem with the proposed query lies in the use of AND's and OR's (and likely missing `(...)`). This statement

> a.word = b.word then join, otherwise compare only a.end_key = b.key.

would translate to:

`AND (a.word= b.word OR a.end_key = b.key)`.

Maybe try it like this:

```
         ON 
              b.word = c.word
          AND
              b.speech = c.speech
          AND
              b.sense = c.sense
          AND 
              (a.word  = b.word OR a.end_key = b.key)
```

---

---

It would be a good idea to test in a sqlite manager (eg command line sqlite3, DB Browser for sqlite) before you try it in python; troubleshooting is much easier. And of course test the `SELECT` before you implement it in a `CREATE TABLE`.

You could clarify your question by showing the desired columns and result in `relations` table that this sample data would create (there is nothing between `b` and `c` that would match on `word, speech, sense`). Also the description of the relationship between `a` and `b` is confusing. In the first paragraph it says `Table a is related with table b through column key`. Should `key` be `word`?